# EPSG conversion and image rotation in folium

Tags: python, coordinate-system, overlay, epsg, folium

I'm using Python's folium library (which uses Leaflet) to display images over a map.

However, my original data uses EPSG:3035 and folium uses EPSG:4326 (WGS84). There is a rotation when converting from one to another.

With pyproj, I'm able to reproject the bounds into 4326 but folium's ImageOverlay function demands a `bounds` argument as follows : `[[lat_min, lon_min], [lat_max, lon_max]]` so I can only specify a "straight" rectangle.

The image below shows the result that I get and the rectangle which the image should fit into.

[image: Current and expected results]

Is it possible to rotate the bounds? How can I display my data at the right place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless leaflet/folium can do this on-the-fly, you need to reproject your image to EPSG:4326. This involves a change of the grid system for your data, and is usually a lossy operation. Its unlikely this is a simple rotation, since you are transforming from a conical projection of the GRS80 ellipsoid to a lat-long coordinate system on the WGS84 ellipsoid.

I'd probably do this by using the `gdalwarp` command line tool, or its interface from QGIS, or similar tools in R. You'll end up with your rotated image within a larger rectangle filled with missing values, which should be rendered as transparent.

The Python `rasterio` package has functionality for raster warping: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: `gdalwarp` can do it indeed. But I'm working with `numpy` arrays in notebooks and I'd like to do it in these notebooks, on the fly. Do you know of any library to do that?

Comment: The reason why I want to do it on-the-fly is that I need to concatenate multiple tiles (which I do with `numpy` arrays) to build the image I display, which is easy with native projection but harder if each tile is warped beforehand. I guess I could create a temporary assembled image with GDAL and then warp it but I think the performance would not be great.

Comment: Try rasterio? See edit.

Comment: Indeed, this can be done with [rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reproject.html?highlight=warp). Thanks a lot!